# Convert Pillow image to Django ImageField

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I am trying to convert a **Pillow** image to **Django ImageField**.

Basically, I:

- Take an `ImageField` as input (from a user submitted form)
- Open it with `Pillow`
- Process it (blur it in that case)
- Pass it back to my Django Form
- Try to save the Form ⚠️

This is at the last step that I have the error `'Image' object has no attribute '_committed'` *(which I believe is that Django is unable to save a Pillow image and that it needs to be converted)*

```py
def upload_media(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image = form.cleaned_data['image']

            pil_image = Image.open(image)
            blurred_image = pil_image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(100))

            post = Post(image=image, blurred_image=blurred_image)
            post.save()

    return redirect('index')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in django file data from request converted into fileupload object . you need to get this image and conver it to byte and the conver it into fileupload object with InMemoryUploadedFile class . output of this class is fileupload object .

```
image = Img.open(field)
image = image.convert('RGB')
image = image.resize((800, 800), Img.ANTIALIAS)
output = io.BytesIO()
image.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=85)
output.seek(0)
new_pic= InMemoryUploadedFile(output, 'ImageField',
                                    field.name,
                                    'image/jpeg',
                                    sys.getsizeof(output), None)
```

Comment: what does `filed.name` stand for here?